# Does this operation exist? What's its name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, math-software

I need to do something like this

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\
B \\
C \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \\
y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n \\
z_1 & z_2 & \cdots & z_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A x_1 & A x_2 & \cdots & A x_n \\
B y_1 & B y_2 & \cdots & B y_n \\
C z_1 & C z_2 & \cdots & C z_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

You get the idea.

I want to know if this operation already has a name, in order to see if my linear algebra library already supports it.

Comment: Take the *"n"* row vectors, multiply each one by $A,B,C,...$. You can quickly implement a looping operation for it.

Comment: Are the elements $A, B, C, x_1, x_2, \dots, y_1, y_2, \dots$ numbers or matrices/vectors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that your RHS can be obtained by matrix multiplication:
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}A&0&0\\0&B&0\\0&0&C\end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\\
    y_1&y_2&\cdots&y_n\\
    z_1&z_2&\cdots&z_n
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The left matrix is a block matrix (in fact a [block diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices)). Your linear algebra library will likely have a way to construct these from an array of smaller matrices, and then you can use matrix multiplication.

Comment: You're right, I'll try it this way.

Comment: If done naively by actually constructing the diagonal matrix as a non-sparse matrix and then multiplying, this will increase the time requirement quite significantly.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of another answer, you might want to take a look at [Hadamard product of matricies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)). Basically you are doing the Hadamard product for $[A,B,C]^T$ and each column of the second matrix.

[Added:] If you know MATLAB, you might want to take a look at the [Element-wise multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html).

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}A&B\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=[Ax+By]$ is different from $\begin{bmatrix}Ax\\By\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @stewbasic: You are right! I have just edited my answer.

Comment: First time I've heard about that one. I always referred to it as *element-wise multiplication*. Are they the same thing? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @almosnow: Well, MATLAB calls it "Element-wise multiplication".